# How can I get a method as a return value?

Tags: java, return

My homework is that my animal "Crab" should turn randomly. My randomly choosen number "n" should be the trigger for a turn. I am a beginner in programming sorry.

I tried to switch between boolean, int and void. It never worked.

```
import greenfoot.*; 

public class Crab extends Animal
{     
    public int zeahler; 
    public int n;* 

    public void act()
    {
       zeahler += zeahler; //zeahler wird hochgezählt
    }

    public boolean aendern()
    {
        n = Greenfoot.getRandomNumber(51);
        if(zeahler> n)  
        return turn(40);
    }

}
```

I expect the crab to turn by 40 degrees but I get the error:  incompatible types: void cannot be converted to boolean

Comment: Does your method `turn(int)` return void? Since you are trying to return the results of that method. If that method returns void you return void on your aendern method.

Comment: That's not your only issue there, your `aendern()` doesn't return something in every (`if`) case.

Comment: Please post the code for turn(int).

Answer (score 1):

I think your turn(int) method should return void. However in your aendern() method you tell her to return void while it returns a boolean. Hence this error:"void cannot be converted to boolean"

You can try this :

```
public boolean aendern()
    {   
        boolean test = false;
        n = Greenfoot.getRandomNumber(51);
        if(zeahler> n) { 
         turn(40);
         test = true;
        }
       return test ;
    }
```